# Titan 0.5.1 Customize object in my node

Tags: titan

I have a problem with Titan 0.5.1. I try to upgrade Titan 0.4.4 to 0.5.1. Currently, I use berkeleyje and i configure like this :

```
BaseConfiguration conf = new BaseConfiguration();

// Storage info
conf.setProperty("storage.directory", directory + File.separator + DB_NAME);
conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "berkeleyje");

// Class info storage
conf.setProperty("attributes.allow-all", "true");
conf.setProperty("attributes.custom.attribute1.attribute-class", "model.Property");
conf.setProperty("attributes.custom.attribute1.serializer-class", "PropertySerializer");

TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

For serialize my object i use :

```
public class PropertySerializer implements AttributeSerializer<Property> {

    @Override
    public Property read(ScanBuffer buffer) {
        Property object = null;
        ArrayList<Byte> records = new ArrayList<Byte>();

        try {
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                records.add(Byte.valueOf(buffer.getByte()));
            }

            Byte[] bytes = records.toArray(new Byte[records.size()]);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes));
            ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            object = (Property) in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return object;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(WriteBuffer out, Property attribute) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutput outobj;

            outobj = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

            outobj.writeObject(attribute);
            byte[] propertybyte = bos.toByteArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < propertybyte.length; i++) {
                out.putByte(propertybyte[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void verifyAttribute(Property value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Property convert(Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Typically, i add a property like this :

```
Vertex r = this.model.addVertex(null);
Property p = new Property();
r.setProperty("object", p);
this.model.commit();
```

But i obtain this error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not commit
>   transaction due to exception during persistence   at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1310)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.blueprints.TitanBlueprintsGraph.commit(TitanBlueprintsGraph.java:60)
>      Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Serializer
>   Restriction: Cannot serialize object of type: class
>   .model.Property   at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer$StandardDataOutput.writeClassAndObject(StandardSerializer.java:160)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.writePropertyValue(EdgeSerializer.java:383)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.writePropertyValue(EdgeSerializer.java:377)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.writeRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:293)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.prepareCommit(StandardTitanGraph.java:485)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.commit(StandardTitanGraph.java:613)
>     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.commit(StandardTitanTx.java:1299)

Can you help me please ? Because, with 0.4.4 version it worked. The new documentation don't help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi,

Please you can delete the name before model.Property ? It is confidential...

So, i write the fully classified class names in my configuration. Maybe, i dont can serializer Property because Titan use a class Property ? I dont know.

Thanks friend.

Comment: I was not allowed to edit my previous comment, so here's my (sanitized) comment again: Try to use the fully classified class name for the type and for the serializer.

Comment: Hello daniel, thanks for your response. Yes i use the fully classified class name. I don't understand why doesn't work...

Comment: I have same issue with 5.2. After _commit()_ I got **Cannot serialize object of type: class java.util.UUID**. Any progress on your side?

Comment: Hello aholub ! Yes i solved that. We must have public int hashCode() and equals method in your class.

After that, the problem is solved.